# Jruby on rails doesn't work

Tags: jruby

I just installed rvm and installed jruby
and gem install rails
rails 5.1
and then a create a new rails 
happends next......

```
ruby bin/rails server
```

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base>
Did you mean?  alias_method
Backtrace for gem load error is:
org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1653:in`method_missing'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/base_ext.rb:13:in `singleton class'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/base_ext.rb:4:in`block in ActiveRecord'
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2831:in `module_eval'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/base_ext.rb:3:in`'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/base_ext.rb:1:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in`require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:1:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in`require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:6:in `<module:(root)>'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in`'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:52:in`'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:3:in`'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:1:in`block in (root)'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733:in `each'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:9:in`block in (root)'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733:in `each'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.22/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:1:in`(root)'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.22/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:2:in `(root)'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in`'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in`block in require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747:in `tap'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in`require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:108:in`require'
/home/jack_zhang/Desktop/jrubyrails/config/application.rb:7:in `(root)'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:1:in`(root)'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `perform'
/home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in`'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in`'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

block in require at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733
  block in require at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733
           require at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
           require at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:108
             at /home/jack_zhang/Desktop/jrubyrails/config/application.rb:7
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
   block in (root) at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:1
               tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747
           perform at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133
           perform at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130
               run at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27
    invoke_command at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
          dispatch at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387
           perform at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63
             at /home/jack_zhang/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.4.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:44
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
             at bin/rails:4

Comment: Are you kidding :) ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22** isn't compatible with Rails 5.x

... you should try the rails-5 branch form the gem's git repository